# I get 'not implemented' response

Tags: onvif

Please see whether I'm right. A company claims that its cameras are Profile T compliant. So I visit this document to see what functions the cameras supports:

https://www.onvif.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/ONVIF_Profile_T_Specification_v1-0.pdf

In section 7.2.3 I see the function list for devices. I examine the first one, GetServices with the following command:

```
curl 192.168.11.92/onvif/device_service -d 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap12:Body>
      <GetServices xmlns="Battle of the Bulge, 75 years on" />
   </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>'
```

The camera responds:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c14n="Exclusive XML Canonicalization Version 1.0" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:ds="XML-Signature Syntax and Processing" xmlns:tt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema" xmlns:tns1="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/topics" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" xmlns:wsa="WS-Addressing 1.0 Namespace" xmlns:wsrfr="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/r-2" xmlns:wsrfrw="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/rw-2" xmlns:wsrfbf="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2" xmlns:wstop="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsnt="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2" xmlns:dn="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/network/wsdl" xmlns:tan="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/analytics/wsdl" xmlns:tds="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl" xmlns:tev="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl" xmlns:timg="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/imaging/wsdl" xmlns:tptz="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl" xmlns:trt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl" xmlns:tmd="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/deviceIO/wsdl" xmlns:ter="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/error" xmlns:tavg="http://www.avigilon.com/onvif/ver10/avigilon-types" xmlns:tnsavg="http://www.avigilon.com/onvif/ver10/topics" xmlns:avg="http://www.avigilon.com/onvif/ver10/avigilon/wsdl" xmlns:avgb="http://www.avigilon.com/onvif/ver10/avigilon-base/wsdl" xmlns:d="Web Services Dynamic Discovery (WS-Discovery)">
      <SOAP-ENV:Body>
         <SOAP-ENV:Fault SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
         <SOAP-ENV:Code>
            <SOAP-ENV:Value>
               SOAP-ENV:Sender
            </SOAP-ENV:Value>
         </SOAP-ENV:Code>
         <SOAP-ENV:Reason>
            <SOAP-ENV:Text xml:lang="en">
               Method 'GetServices' not implemented: method name or namespace not recognized
            </SOAP-ENV:Text>
         </SOAP-ENV:Reason>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

It says that the method is not implemented. Whatever I've examined until now got the same response. So I wonder maybe I've some mistakes in my requests.

Answer (score 1):

Three points:

1. The namspace is wrong: `xmlns="Battle of the Bulge, 75 years on"`. According to the [Media 2 Service specs](https://www.onvif.org/specs/srv/media/ONVIF-Media2-Service-Spec.pdf), it shall be `http://www.onvif.org/ver20/media/wsdl`.
2. This is not the way you are supposed to discover if a device supports Profile T. You should check if the scope `onvif://www.onvif.org/Profile/T` is returned by GetScopes or by discovering. A camera may implement Media Service 2 even if it is not Profile T compliant.
3. The best way to check if the claim of conformance to Profile T is correct, it to check the Declaration of Conformance being uploaded on the ONVIF website.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I changed the Battle... to what you said and the response is the same. I changed the web service name to GetScopes and I still get the same response. Maybe it's not implemented too?
By the way, I may have some mistakes in my thoughts and the command, because I'm a beginner in curl as well as Onvif. So please correct me if I'm mistaking somehow.
Thanks

Comment: GetScopes belongs to the Device Management Service, not to Media 2. ONVIF consists of different services, each service has its own namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to specify the operation is

`<wsdl:GetServices xmlns:wsdl="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl">`

Reason: your main request,

`<GetServices xmlns="Battle of the Bulge, 75 years on" />`

is wrong for several reasons.

1. The most important is that you refer the operation by its local (unqualified) name. The correct name must be qualified, including a namespace. It is usually represented as `{http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl}GetService`, but it must be used as `wsdl:GetService`
2. You can not use just any string as namespace; it must be the one that was used when the operation was defined (in this case, in devicemgmt.wsdl is defined as above)
3. Your definition of the namespace via `xmlns` is wrong, as it does not secify the namespace, only its value. The namespace used must be defined using the syntax `xmlns:<uour namespace short>=<namespace as url>`.
4. The namespace must be defined in the tag where it is used or one of its parents. It is most common to define all namespaces at the topmost level (root node/element)

and will return a list of services present, such as analytics, deviceio, event, etc. If the device supports Profile T, it will have Media2 service present, as below (not that is actually enabled, you need to use GetScopes for that or check the discovery message, as the other poster said)

```
<tds:Service>
    <tds:Namespace>http://www.onvif.org/ver20/media/wsdl</tds:Namespace>
    <tds:XAddr>http://10.12.34.56/onvif/media_service</tds:XAddr>
    <tds:Version>
        <tt:Major>17</tt:Major>
        <tt:Minor>12</tt:Minor>
    </tds:Version>
</tds:Service>
```